# ASP.NET Core application not starting in IIS (targets net461)

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core

I have .NET Core web application targeting `net461` framework. And I tried to publish it to IIS. What I have followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) and after accessing page I got this:

[image]

I checked following:

- There is folder **.\logs\stdout** and IIS has full control to read/write, logging is enabled but not log file is created
- AppPool has selected **No Managed Code**
- In **Event Viewer** no errors are shown under **Windows Logs/Application**
- In IIS logs there is no useful information

Then I decided that I'll make empty .NET Core app also target `net461` and deploy it to IIS. I followed exact same steps and this empty "Hello World!" app works.

Then I noticed that application that does not work have ASP.NET section and other don't. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: double check your app pool

Comment: Do you have a `stdoutLogEnabled="true"` attribute on your `<aspNetCore />` element in your web.config?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by targeting `net461` framework with .NET Core web application. Can you right click your asp.net web application project in Solution explorer and then click Edit and check the `<TargetFramework>`. I think your web application is targeting .NET Framework and not .NET Core thats why when you are trying to host it under AppPool with `No Managed Code` it is causing error

Comment: Can you run the app alone successfully?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Looks like that was not it. ASP.NET Core app can target `net461` framework and runs under AppPool with `No Managed Code`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I set environment variables `ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS` and `ASPNETCORE_CAPTURESTARTUPERRORS` to `true`, I was able to see exception in browser and successfully debug a problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1